# Where to make the changes to enable an InfoPath 2007 Form to open in a browser.

Tags: infopath

At present an Infopath 2007 form will not open in a browser. I am looking for a way to force
it to open in a browser and a description of how to do this,

Comment: First of all, what is your edition of SharePoint ?

Comment: It is SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise edition

Comment: Is it a form from a form library? a standalone form displayed by the browser form webpart? If it's the former, check in the list settings that the form should open in web browser. Also check that the Enterprise features (web and site) are activated.

Answer (score 2):

[Make sure that InfoPath Forms Services (SharePoint Server 2010) are configured](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262263.aspx)   (in Central Administration under Farm Administrators SharePoint group account)

For a library form check [Sharepoint workbook opening in Microsoft InfoPath Filler 2010 rather than Microsoft InfoPath Designer 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15771/sharepoint-workbook-opening-in-microsoft-infopath-filler-2010-rather-than-micros), for a **Sharepoint List Form** check [this my answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/40472/8319)